# How to get the lastest NuGet Nearby version?

Tags: android-studio, xamarin.android, nuget, google-nearby

I try develop a program use Google API Nearby use xamarin

in android studio, the lastest version of nearby service is 16.0.0 that updated on october 2018

but the lastest nuget nearby version i found in xamarin is 60.1142.1 that updated on march 2018 which equal to 11.4.2 in the android studio

How to get the lastest NuGet Nearby version like in the android studio?
Because the i have a trouble to use 11.4.2 because it need GoogleApiClient as parameter

```
    public NearbyService()
    {
        Context = Application.Context;
        ConnectionsClient = NearbyClass.Connections;
        SetGoogleApiClient();
    }

    public void SetGoogleApiClient()
    {
        GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Context)
               .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
               .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
               .AddApi(NearbyClass.CONNECTIONS_API)
               .Build();
        if (!GoogleApiClient.IsConnected)
            GoogleApiClient.Connect();
    }

    public void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        NearbyConnections = new NearbyConnections();
        ConnectionLifeCycleCallbackService = new ConnectionLifeCycleCallbackService(this, new PayloadCallbackService(this));
        EndPointDiscoveryCallbackService = new EndPointDiscoveryCallbackService(this, ConnectionLifeCycleCallbackService);
    }


    public void OnConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
    {
        if (!GoogleApiClient.IsConnected)
            GoogleApiClient.Connect();
    }
```

Then in my MainActivity I will call

```
    protected override void OnRestart()
    {
        base.OnRestart();
        if (NearbyService.GoogleApiClient != null && !NearbyService.GoogleApiClient.IsConnected)
            NearbyService.GoogleApiClient.Connect();
    }
```

Comment: Check the Include pre-release checkbox and then download that if you want

Comment: will there be a problem if we use pre-release?
sorry im new in xamarin

Comment: Yes there could be problems that is why it only available like that, i would suggest you rather use stable and tell me whatever issue you are facing and i might know how to help

Comment: my problem is when the GoogleApiClient got disconnected, I always try to reconnect use GoogleApiClient.Connect() and it always success and will trigger OnConnected. But when I check the status use IsConnected, its always return false and my code that use GoogleApiClient as parameter always get stuck without error

Comment: Share your code here please, let me have a look

Comment: Ok Sir.... I updated my post. The GoogleApiClient will be use in ConnectionLifeCycleCallbackService  and EndPointDiscoveryCallbackService  thats why I declared them in there

Comment: So isConnected is never true is what you are telling me?

Comment: yes. isConnected is never true even though .Connect() always success

Comment: From your code have a logic problem.It seems that calling GoogleApiClient in the code is not unique. Every time you judge GoogleApiClient, it is a new object, so that it is invalid every time you judge the connection. It is recommended that you modify the SetGoogleApiClient method to ensure that GoogleApiClient is the only one in use.`public void SetGoogleApiClient(){if (null != GoogleApiClient){GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Context) ... } ... }`